# Temporary views in CouchDB and Python

Tags: python-3.x, couchdb

I'm trying using python to retrive information from CouchDB.
I'm following this guide: https://readthedocs.org/projects/couchdb-python/downloads/pdf/latest/
Now, this is my code:

```
movie_id = "1721"
map_fun = '''function (doc) {
  if(doc.MovieId == movie_id)
    emit(doc.Rating, null);
}'''

for row in db.query(map_fun):
    print(row.key)
```

when I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
ServerError: (410, ('gone', 'Temporary views are not supported in CouchDB'))
```

I'm not an expert, but the guide say to do this, what's the problem?

From Graphic interface in Chrome this view works good.

PS: I'm running python 3.8 using Spyder4 in Anaconda and CouchDB 3.0.0

Comment: Generally, I would avoid using temporary views. You can create a persistent view and just delete it after you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Temporary view support was dropped at 2.0.  That technique has been long unavailable - [Temporary views are no longer supported.](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/whatsnew/2.0.html?highlight=%22temporary%20views%22#upgrade-notes)

Comment: Thanks for now. One last thing, is it possible to create/delete these views from python? Since it would be too many, would it be cheaper to query and map results by myself?

Comment: @Malotino adding a design document is just like any other document, but after an upsert the server begins building an index according to the map function;  I would avoid any possible churn from creating and dropping views at a high rate...YMMV.  Perhaps it's possible to refactor the temporary views approach to some clever persistent views?  That's only something you can answer.